# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Tags: spring-boot, multi-tenant, maven-dependency, transactionmanager, entitymanagerfactory

Suddenly started having this error on my Multitenant code.....Which is Working fine on my local system but not working with pipeline created jar, i have tried with azure pipeline and github actions pipeline too i am getting the same issue.

If i deploy manually created jar in my VM then it works fine too, but doesn't work with pipeline created jar.

Error:

```
19:53:30.010 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'masterdb-persistence-unit'
19:53:30.014 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - masterdb-connection-pool - Shutdown initiated...
19:53:30.036 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - masterdb-connection-pool - Shutdown completed.
19:53:30.045 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
19:53:30.107 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener -
 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
19:53:30.228 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [com/continuum/multitenant/tenant/config/TenantDatabaseConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'transactionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
        at com.continuum.config.ContinuumMain.main(ContinuumMain.java:13)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

It suddenly stopped working without doing any code changes, just redeployed using azure pipeline.

I tried defining versions to dependencies, deleted all local repositories and build again still it works fine on local but not on my remote vm machine.

TenantDatabaseConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.tenant.repos.repositories", "com.test.tenant.repos.entity" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.tenant.repos.repositories", "com.test.tenant.service",
        "com.test.serviceImpl" }, entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class TenantDatabaseConfig {

    @Bean(name = "tenantJpaVendorAdapter")
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory tenantEntityManager) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(tenantEntityManager);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * The multi tenant connection provider
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
    @ConditionalOnBean(name = "masterEntityManagerFactory")
    public MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider() {
        // Autowires the multi connection provider
        return new DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl();
    }

    /**
     * The current tenant identifier resolver
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "currentTenantIdentifierResolver")
    public CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver() {
        return new CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl();
    }

    /**
     * Creates the entity manager factory bean which is required to access the JPA
     * functionalities provided by the JPA persistence provider, i.e. Hibernate in
     * this case.
     *
     * @param connectionProvider
     * @param tenantResolver
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    @ConditionalOnBean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider") MultiTenantConnectionProvider connectionProvider,
            @Qualifier("currentTenantIdentifierResolver") CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver tenantResolver) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        // All tenant related entities, repositories and service classes must be scanned
        emfBean.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[] { "com.test.tenant.repos.repositories", "com.test.tenant.repos.entity" });
        emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName("tenantdb-persistence-unit");
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, connectionProvider);
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantResolver);
        properties.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
        properties.put(Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
        // properties.put(Environment.IMPLICIT_NAMING_STRATEGY,
        // SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        // properties.put(Environment.PHYSICAL_NAMING_STRATEGY,
        // PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.class.getName());
        properties.put(Environment.PHYSICAL_NAMING_STRATEGY, PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl.class.getName());
        properties.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "none");
        emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return emfBean;
    }
}
```

MasterDatabaseConfig.class.

```
 @Configuration
@Lazy
@Import(BatchConfig.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.tenant.repos.repositories", "com.test.tenant.repos.entity" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.multitenant.mastertenant.entity",
        "com.test.multitenant.mastertenant.repository",
        "com.test.tenant.repos.repositories","com.test.tenant.repos.repositories", "com.test.tenant.service",
        "com.test.serviceImpl" }, entityManagerFactoryRef = "masterEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "masterTransactionManager")
public class MasterDatabaseConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MasterDatabaseConfig.class);

    private MasterDatabaseConfigProperties masterDbProperties;

    @Lazy
    public MasterDatabaseConfig(MasterDatabaseConfigProperties masterDbProperties) {
        this.masterDbProperties = masterDbProperties;
    }

    // Create Master Data Source using master properties and also configure HikariCP
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "masterDataSource")
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(masterDbProperties.getUsername());
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(masterDbProperties.getPassword());
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(masterDbProperties.getUrl());
        hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName(masterDbProperties.getDriverClassName());
        hikariDataSource.setPoolName(masterDbProperties.getPoolName());
        // HikariCP settings
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(masterDbProperties.getMaxPoolSize());
        hikariDataSource.setMinimumIdle(masterDbProperties.getMinIdle());
        hikariDataSource.setConnectionTimeout(masterDbProperties.getConnectionTimeout());
        hikariDataSource.setIdleTimeout(masterDbProperties.getIdleTimeout());
        LOG.info("Setup of masterDataSource succeeded.");
        return hikariDataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "masterEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean masterEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        // Set the master data source
        em.setDataSource(masterDataSource());
        // The master tenant entity and repository need to be scanned
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.test");
        // Setting a name for the persistence unit as Spring sets it as
        // 'default' if not defined
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("masterdb-persistence-unit");
        // Setting Hibernate as the JPA provider
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        // Set the hibernate properties
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        LOG.info("Setup of masterEntityManagerFactory succeeded.");
        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "masterTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager masterTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("masterEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    // Hibernate configuration properties
    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "none");
        // properties.put(Environment.IMPLICIT_NAMING_STRATEGY,
        // SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put(Environment.PHYSICAL_NAMING_STRATEGY, PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl.class.getName());
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have two different classes (MasterDatabaseConfig.classs and TenantDatabaseConfig.class) for my multitenant application code.